# Print from wizard

Tags: odoo-11

I would like to print a report from wizard. In this wizard I recover the order selected and call to report_action function with the orders selected.

The problem is that I don't know how to send the orders to this function. This is the code:

```
def _get_default_orders(self): 
  return self.env['sale.order'].browse(self.env.context.get('active_ids')) 

order_ids = fields.Many2many('sale.order', string='Orders', default=_get_default_orders) 

@api.multi 
def processed_orders(self): 
  list = [] 
  for orders in self: 
  if orders.order_ids: 
       list.append(orders) 

  datas = { 
    'ids': list, 
    'model': 'sale.order', 
  } 

  return self.env.ref('aloha_reports_templates.custom_report_sale_order').sudo().report_action(self, data=datas)
```

Odoo generate an error because I don't send properly the parameters to the report_action.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per your example first, in your system, there is must be aloha_reports_templates.custom_report_sale_order action available for the report.

Let me show you an example from odoo 11 community code
File: **account/models/account_invoice.py** method(**invoice_print**)

```
@api.multi
def invoice_print(self):
    """ Print the invoice and mark it as sent, so that we can see more
        easily the next step of the workflow
    """
    self.ensure_one()
    self.sent = True
    if self.user_has_groups('account.group_account_invoice'):
        return self.env.ref('account.account_invoices').report_action(self)
    else:
        return self.env.ref('account.account_invoices_without_payment').report_action(self)
```

As per above code in odoo 11 community there is already account_invoices report action already created as below (**account/views/account_report.xml**).

```
  <report 
        id="account_invoices"
        model="account.invoice"
        string="Invoices"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="account.report_invoice_with_payments"
        file="account.report_invoice_with_payments"
        attachment="(object.state in ('open','paid')) and ('INV'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
        print_report_name="(object._get_printed_report_name())"
        groups="account.group_account_invoice"
    />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's true. I have a report called aloha_reports_templates.custom_report_sale_order.

I know this example but I have several differences

1.- I want to call to the report from a wizard so I have to recover the selected orders and after that, send this information to the report.

2.- I can't send self to the report because I'm in the wizard, no in the orders tree page.

I need to collect the selected orders and, after that, send to the report. This is the reason I'm trying to use the report_action function. But my problem is with the parameters to use in this function.

Thanks